# How to start a Jenkins multibranch pipeline build from the command line (cli)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Currently I can start a Jenkins job using the cli.

Example:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://buildserver:8080 build Job_Name
```

I am playing around with the Jenkins multibranch pipeline feature and have not figured out how to start this type of job using the above command.

Any ideas how I can start a pipeline build via above cli?

Comment: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://buildserver:8080 build Job_Name` works perfectly with pipelines jobs... Could you please provide more details about what exactly is failing ? Do you get an error message ?

Comment: Maybe the standard "pipeline" job can start this way.  I am using the "multibranch pipeline" job.  When I run the job it fails with this error:                                 # java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://buildserver01:8080 build GIT_Pipeline

ERROR: No such job 'GIT_Pipeline'; perhaps you meant '
TEST_int'?

Comment: Sorry I missed the multibranch parameter ;) Please see my answer below !

Comment: Thanks for the help, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

On a multibranch pipeline, the job name is made of both the project name and the branch because a job is actually a build on one branch, you can see the global pipeline as just a container.
In the end, if your pipeline configuration is named `your-project` and you want to launch the job for the `newfeature` branch, you should do :

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://buildserver:8080 build your-project/newfeature
```

Also, the full project name is shown by Jenkins as shown above :

[image]

Comment: How to trigger scan for new branches for which the job has not been created in Jenkins yet?